# how to create an intent to stop / pause / reset the Clock Timer not the scheduler?

Tags: timer, resume

I would like to reset/ pause / resume the clock timer which is in the AlarmClock using an intent (mainly would be from another device).
the following code outlines my activity to launch the timer with a predefined value. My question is how to reset/ pause / resume that timer from the same activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // launch the timer with a predefined value
    Intent startTimer=new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);
    startTimer.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, 300);
    startTimer.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, false);
    startTimer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startTimer);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```